# Does SharePoint 2013 automatically overwrite documents?

Tags: sharepoint-online

If I were to upload a Word Document with the same name that has been edited on my desktop outside of SharePoint, will SharePoint automatically overwrite the Word Document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will override the file if you drag and drop it into the library or use the file upload option and tick the check box to over write file. Using Explorer view should prompt you if you want to over write it.

Comment: It didn't ask me if I wanted to Overwrite it using Explorer. I'm not worried because I did want it to be Overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it overwrites it. And it will create a version of the old one if versioning is turned on for your document library.